# Get unique lines and its maximum value using shell tools

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

how can I get unique lines with its max value using shell tool? I want to sort -r by pattern like /path/package_t-CH1- and then use "uniq" tore remove the other lines that matches the first pattern, and also get the max value of the matches lines

Something like sort -r -n  "/CH1-pattern.txt" | uniq

```
/path/package_t-CH1-20170828_191558.txt 
/path/package_t-CH1-20170828_194112.txt 
/path/package_f-CH1-20170828_191616.txt 
/path/package_f-CH1-20170828_191216.txt 
/path/package_t-CH1-20170828_192731.txt
```

Expected result:

```
/path/package_t-CH1-20170828_194112.txt
/path/package_f-CH1-20170828_191616.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell tools you mentioned won't do that in a single command. You could either use `perl`, or write a small script like this:

```
packages=`cat list.txt|cut -f1 -d- |sort -u`
for p in $packages; do grep $p list.txt |sort -r |head -1; done
```